# why does this error occurred out of nowhere and wouldn't debug my code?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, libphonenumber

A problem occurred configuring project ':libphonenumber_plugin'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':libphonenumber_plugin' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':libphonenumber_plugin' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

this error occured out of nowhere and i cant debug my code in any way

i tried deleting thhis plugin and even getting an older vesion of my code and still the same issue occures

Comment: Try running `flutter create .` in the root folder of your app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try running `flutter clean`